# passing arg 1 of `foo' from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, gcc, ansi-c

Why this shows warning:

```
#include<stdio.h>
foo (const char **p)
{ 

}

int main(int argc , char **argv)
{
    foo(argv);
}
```

But following does not show any warning

```
char * cp;
const char *ccp;
ccp = cp;
```

The first code snippet shows warning passing arg 1 of `foo` from incompatible pointer type. But the second snippet does not show any warning. Both are `const` pointers

Answer (score 1):

See the [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html)

You can cast in order to remove warnings:

```
foo((const char **)argv);
```

But as FAQ says: the need for such a cast may indicate a deeper problem which the cast doesn't really fix.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your compilation flags, you might need an explicit cast when assigning cp's content to ccp.

Answer (score 0):

In the first version you are casting between two different types of pointer not simply adding a `const` to the pointer.

- `char **` is a pointer to a (pointer to a `char`)
- `const char **` is a pointer to a (pointer to a `const char`)

As you can see these pointer point to different types similar to the more obviously questionable:

```
int *i;
double *d;
d = i;
```

In your second example you see that you can cast from a pointer to a const pointer so if you were to apply this to your situation you would need to have a const pointer to (a pointer to a `char`).

```
foo(char * const *p);
```